# Methods and their comparison for reading huge log file in perl

Tags: perl, file-io

I have a huge log file (around 5-10 milion lines). I need to traverse each and every line and do processing. I am seeing huge runtime.

I am aware of two methods of reading files in `perl` as depicted below.

**(1)** How do I compare performance of different methods? Any bench-marking mechanism?

**(2)** What's the most efficient way and why? Is there any *third* and better method available?

One option is to implement both methods and check for run-time. But here I trying understand what makes them run faster or slower. It would be appreciable if you could help me in this regards.

**Method 1**

```
open FOPEN, '<', $file or die $!;
my @lines = <FOPEN>;
chomp @lines;
foreach (@lines) {
    # do something on $_
}
```

**Method 2**

```
open FOPEN, '<', $file or die $!;
while (<FOPEN>) {
    chomp;
    # do something on $_
}
```

Comment: It's really hard to benchmark file IO because of caching.

Comment: @ikegami aha! now I get it why I don't get same performance all the time even with same code!

Comment: @jkshah My 2 cents: when benchmarking IO heavy programs, it's best to stop all IO-bound programs/tasks on your system and then run the program in question several times. On the first run all the necessary blocks from the disk will get cached in memory, and subsequent runs will give exhibit consistent timings as all the necessary data should originate from the OS disk cache. Of course, none of this applies if the size of the IO set in question exceeds the memory limits of the system.

Comment: @Nikhil but the system we generally use are shared and many user run different jobs on the same machine. So I think I will not be able to control programs/task as you suggested!

Comment: @Nikhil, He's trying to benchmark the IO itself, so your suggestion would totally invalidate the test.

Comment: @ikegami My suggestion was for IO-heavy programs, not the IO itself. I believe then you were referring to disk-caching and not the OS cache?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Method 2 is definitely the way to go. Method 1 will copy the entire file into memory (inside the variable @lines). If your log file is > 1 GB, expect your program to crash out. Method 2 will iterate over the file line-by-line, and maintain an near-constant memory usage.

Hope this helps.

EDIT: (forgot to talk about the benchmarking part)

You can use a module like [Benchmark](http://perldoc.perl.org/Benchmark.html) to compare the performance of both methods over several iterations. A very handy tool. You will find method 2 will out-perform method 1 by a decent margin for a very large file.

Comment: `chomp @lines` is fine. It chomps each element of the array. [The documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) says *"If you chomp a list, each element is chomped, and the total number of characters removed is returned"*.

Answer (score 8):

Unless you need to process the lines of the file out of order, you should *definitely* read it in a `while` loop, as absorbing the entire file into an array is just squandering memory. The Perl IO system will make this as efficient as it can by buffering the file reads and passing each line of data from the buffer as it is requested.

There is also probably no need to `chomp` each line. A spare newline on the end of your string is unlikely to matter.

Depending on what you want to do with the files, it may be appropriate to preprocess the input to a smaller file (or files) that contain just the information of interest.

Always use lexical filehandles, i.e.

```
open my $fh, '<', $file or die $!;
while (<$fh>) {
    # do something on $_
}
```

This is nothing to do with efficiency; it is simply good practice.

Answer (score 1):

If file size is large and you are reading the entire file , consider doing sysread with none blocking IO , some example is found here : http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl/cookbook/ch07_15.htm
or search for "perl sysread non blocking"